# Unable to reuse flutter dropdownbuttonformfield

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to build my 2nd flutter app. In one of the screen I have a tab with two tabpages namely 'Billing Address' & 'Shipping Address'. Both the tabpages have similar controls like some TextFormFields and one DropDownButtonFormField.
[image]

Now, I have the code for the DropDownButtonFormField in a separate file, which I am calling from the above mentioned screen twice.

Code for DropDownFormField:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:hot/controller/general_controller.dart';

class MyStatesDropdown1 extends StatelessWidget {
  MyStatesDropdown1({super.key});
  final GeneralController _generalController = Get.put(GeneralController());

  final istates = [
    {'scode': '35', 'sname': 'Andaman & Nicobar Islands'},
    {'scode': '37', 'sname': 'Andhra Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '12', 'sname': 'Arunachal Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '18', 'sname': 'Assam'},
    {'scode': '10', 'sname': 'Bihar'},
    {'scode': '04', 'sname': 'Chandigarh'},
    {'scode': '22', 'sname': 'Chattisgarh'},
    {'scode': '26', 'sname': 'Dadra & Nagar Haveli & Daman & Diu'},
    {'scode': '07', 'sname': 'Delhi'},
    {'scode': '30', 'sname': 'Goa'},
    {'scode': '24', 'sname': 'Gujarat'},
    {'scode': '06', 'sname': 'Haryana'},
    {'scode': '02', 'sname': 'Himachal Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '01', 'sname': 'Jammu & Kashmir'},
    {'scode': '20', 'sname': 'Jharkhand'},
    {'scode': '29', 'sname': 'Karnataka'},
    {'scode': '32', 'sname': 'Kerala'},
    {'scode': '38', 'sname': 'Ladakh'},
    {'scode': '31', 'sname': 'Lakshwadeep'},
    {'scode': '23', 'sname': 'Madhya Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '27', 'sname': 'Maharashtra'},
    {'scode': '14', 'sname': 'Manipur'},
    {'scode': '17', 'sname': 'Meghalaya'},
    {'scode': '15', 'sname': 'Mizoram'},
    {'scode': '13', 'sname': 'Nagaland'},
    {'scode': '21', 'sname': 'Odisha'},
    {'scode': '34', 'sname': 'Puducherry'},
    {'scode': '03', 'sname': 'Punjab'},
    {'scode': '08', 'sname': 'Rajasthan'},
    {'scode': '11', 'sname': 'Sikkim'},
    {'scode': '33', 'sname': 'Tamil Nadu'},
    {'scode': '36', 'sname': 'Telangana'},
    {'scode': '16', 'sname': 'Tripura'},
    {'scode': '09', 'sname': 'Uttar Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '15', 'sname': 'Uttrakhand'},
    {'scode': '19', 'sname': 'West Bengal'}
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
                child: DropdownButtonFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  hintText: 'Select State',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800)),
              value: _generalController.selectedState.value == ''
                  ? null
                  : _generalController.selectedState.value,
              onChanged: (newVal) {
                _generalController.updtSelectedState(newVal.toString());
              },
              items: istates.map((Map item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item['scode'], child: Text(item['sname']));
              }).toList(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
              iconSize: 42,
            )),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

The Problem: When I select any state from the DropdownButtonFormField in Tab1, the same value is automatically getting selected in Tab2 Dropdown as well and vice versa. I want the Dropdown buttons to behave as if they are two different instances. How can I achieve this? Please help me with some codes. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is custom dropdown for multiple usage.

```
  const MyCustomDropDown({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.items,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String value;
  final Function(String newValue) onChanged;
  final List<Map<String, String>> items;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
                child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isDense: true,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  hintText: 'Select State',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade800)),
              value: value,
              onChanged: (newVal) => onChanged(newVal??""),
              items: items.map((Map item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item['scode'], child: Text(item['sname']));
              }).toList(),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
              iconSize: 42,
            )),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

This is **GetX controller**
You need to define multiple instant for multiple dropdown state value.

```
class GeneralController extends GetxController {
  final istates = [
    {'scode': '35', 'sname': 'Andaman & Nicobar Islands'},
    {'scode': '37', 'sname': 'Andhra Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '12', 'sname': 'Arunachal Pradesh'},
    {'scode': '18', 'sname': 'Assam'},
    {'scode': '10', 'sname': 'Bihar'},
    {'scode': '04', 'sname': 'Chandigarh'},
    {'scode': '22', 'sname': 'Chattisgarh'},
    {'scode': '26', 'sname': 'Dadra & Nagar Haveli & Daman & Diu'},
    {'scode': '07', 'sname': 'Delhi'},
    {'scode': '30', 'sname': 'Goa'},
    {'scode': '24', 'sname': 'Gujarat'},
    {'scode': '06', 'sname': 'Haryana'}
  ];

  var stateBillingValue = ''.obs;
  var stateShippingValue =''.obs; 

  void updateBillingState(String newValue) =>
      stateBillingValue.value = newValue;

  void updateShippingState(String newValue) =>
      stateShippingValue.value = newValue;
}
```

This is **Usage**. Provide **callback function** and **value state** from parent widget for flexible handling.

```
class MyView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyView> createState() => _MyViewState();
}

class _MyViewState extends State<MyView> {
  final GeneralController _generalController = Get.put(GeneralController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          MyCustomDropDown(
            value: _generalController.stateBillingValue.value,
            onChanged: (newValue) =>
                _generalController.updateBillingState(newValue),
            items: _generalController.istates,
          ),
          MyCustomDropDown(
            value: _generalController.stateShippingValue.value,
            onChanged: (newValue) =>
                _generalController.updateShippingState(newValue),
            items: _generalController.istates,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The above code  compiles without any issue but shows error when the app is run. Please see my original question for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need separate controllers for each dropdown. I don't know GetX too much, but in your case it seems the same controller instance is used for both dropdowns.

Comment: it doesn't need two controller for simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below code it will work,

Controller code :

```
class GeneralController extends GetxController {
  var stateBillingValue = ''.obs, stateShippingValue = ''.obs; // use this value according to your requirement.

  void updateState(String newValue, bool isShipping) {
    if (isShipping) {
      stateShippingValue.value = newValue;
    } else {
      stateBillingValue.value = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

view screen code:

```
_generalController.updateState(newValue, true); //if you are in shipping page pass true otherwise false
```

Answer (score 0):

`Get.put` will probably create a single instance of that controller. You need separate instances for each dropdown. You can check this: https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/652#issuecomment-699720426

Basically, you can tag the controller and request it by tag

```
Get.put(Controller(), tag: 'item 1 controller');

// option 1: using Get.find()
Controller controller = Get.find(tag: 'item 1 controller');

// option 2: using GetBuilder
GetBuilder<Controller>(
   tag: 'item 1 controller',
   builder: () => YourWidget()
)

// option 3: using GetX
GetX<Controller>(
   tag: 'item 1 controller',
   builder: () => YourWidget()
)
```